# Transmission Swap – how to modify mounts?

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, corolla

My car has in a Toyota 4e engine which uses a Corolla 3 speed transmission. The transmission is faulty so I would like to change it to a 4 speed Toyota Starlet transmission. The Starlet uses the same engine. The engines are mounted in two  different places. How would I get the original 3-speed mounts to work on the 4-speed?

Comment: You'd need to have custom mounts made. Or modify the frame to accept the 4 speed mounts. Maybe both.

Comment: What years are the chassis and engine are you working with?